# Show master status returns empty set of rows

Tags: mysql, replication

Hi currently I am working on implementing data replication on MYSQL for my project. While working on master file configurations on windows when I am trying to check the status of master, it returns empty set. It means it is not locating mysql-bin file and its position. I have made changes in ini file but the changes are not getting reflected. Can you please advise how I can enable binary loggings in windows configuration Please review and advise

Currently it shows like this
[image]

It should be like this
[image]

Comment: did you restart the service after making config file changes?

Comment: it works now. I just restarted all services. Thank you

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variables for MySQL that are not dynamic (cannot be changed inflight) and require a service restart. This includes some of the binary log specific variables. Consult the MySQL documentation for further info on each variables as and when you discover you need to update their values.

Restarting the process from the service manager should allow these new settings to take hold.